# Checking understanding of basis notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, change-of-basis

As I understand it, if I just write $\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}^T$ it is assumed that the components, $a$, $b$, and $c$ refer to the coefficients of the *standard basis* vectors in the linear combination of them that produces $\mathbf{v}$.

Whereas if I write $\left[\mathbf{v}\right]_B = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}^T$ then it's understood that the components of $\mathbf{v}$ refer to the coefficients of the vectors in the basis $B$ in the linear combination that produces $\mathbf{v}$.

But in general, if I'm told that there is a vector space $V$ that has a basis, $C$, do I still assume that $\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}^T$ refers to the standard basis, rather than $C$? I suppose this also hinges on whether the standard basis always exists? (Seems like it must for finite dimensional real vector spaces, just keep having vectors with only a single 1 and all other components 0, but I don't know if that generalizes to the whole menagerie of infinite dimensional spaces and arbitrary fields)

Comment: $\mathbf{v}$ generally refers to the vector itself, and writing something like $\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}^T$ implies you're writing $\mathbf{v}$ as shorthand for $[\mathbf{v}]_E$, $E$ denoting the standard basis. This of course, does not apply to spaces where we don't have a well-known 'standard basis', in which case, '$\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}^T$' would be nonsensical. (See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2121031/243059)

Comment: It is common that all coordinates are given in a standard basis unless otherwise indicated.

Comment: To be completely fair with you, there is no point in specifying the basis as long as all objects that are considered (vectors, maps, etc.) are "expressed" in the same basis

Comment: Also, $v$ itself may be the $n$-tuple of coordinates in the stadard basis.